# Android ClassCastException by referencing fragment in viewmodel

Tags: java, android, fragment, viewmodel

I was having some problem when trying to reference the fragment in my viewmodel class. Here is the part where my fragment call the viewmodel:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonExport)
void buttonExportClicked(View v){
    SummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SummaryViewModel.class);
    summaryViewModel.export(webViewResult);
}
```

In the viewmodel where I tried to access the context as well as Activity:

```
public void exportSelfTestSummary(WebView webViewResult) {
    Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.show();
    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(context, webViewResult, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {
        ....
}
```

And the error message I am getting:

```
07-02 02:34:01.922 3563-3563/com.mainapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mainapp, PID: 3563
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mainapp.App cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at com.mainapp.viewmodel.SummaryViewModel.export(SummaryViewModel.java:218)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**

```
@Inject
public SummaryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it clear enough, you cannot cast `Application` to `Activity`

What you are doing is get the application context, which will return an `Application` class:

```
Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext();
```

If you are inside a fragment, just simply use `fragment.getActivity()`

Comment: How can I change this line: Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext(); to fragment.getActivity? As in I do not want to pass the fragment as parameter into that function

Comment: How do you construct your `ViewModel` now? Post part of its code. Besides, where is the method `getApplication` come from? As far as I know, `getApplication` method only available in `Activity`

Comment: Edited question!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a ClassCastException because you are trying to cast the application into an Activity.

```
Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext();
```

getApplication() method returns the App class and so does the getApplicationContext() method, which cannot be used to get the Activity.

You should never use a reference to an Activity or Fragment in your ViewModel. Your UI should never be modified from your ViewModel. ViewModel should only contain data used to modify your UI.

As an example:

Fragment/Activity:

```
 SummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SummaryViewModel.class);
 LiveData<WebResult> data = summaryViewModel.getWebViewDataInBackgroundThread();

 //observe on this data for changes in your activity/fragment
 data.observe(this, Observer {
    @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final WebResult result) {
                // Update the UI, 
               Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext();
             final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
             progressDialog.show();
             PdfView.createWebPrintJob(context, webViewResult, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {
             ....
            }
  })
```

In your ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<WebResult> getWebViewDataInBackgroundThread() {
    // getdata and return as LiveData
}
```

Read more on [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

It not a good practice to use `Context` and Activity Lifecycle related staff specially view inside `ViewModel`. `ViewModel` will only hold data and make a connection between data and view. Create `ProgressDialog` inside `Activity` or `Fragment`. Use `ViewModel` for your business logic. Create a `LiveData` for `ProgressDialog` state in `ViewModle`. Change `LiveData` value and observe it in `Activity` or `Fragment`. So you can decide when to show `ProgressDialog` or when to hide it. Your view is inside `Activity` or `Fragment` and there is no possibility of MemoryLeak.

As @tam-huynh mentioned your problem is you trying to cast Application Context to `Activity` that is not valid.

Create `LiveData` in `ViewModel`

```
private MutableLiveData<Integer> progressDialogState;

public LiveData<Integer> getProgressDialogStateAsObservable(){
    return progressDialogState;
}

public void setProgressDialogState(int value){
    progressDialogState.setValue(value);
}


public void exportSelfTestSummary(WebView webViewResult) {
    //Activity context = (Activity) getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    //final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    //progressDialog.show();
    setProgressDialogState(1)
    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(context, webViewResult, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {
        ....

   // after work done set value to 0 
    //setProgressDialogState(0) 
}
```

Observe it in `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
   viewModel.getProgressDialogStateAsObservable().observe(getActivity(), state -> {
        if (state == 1) {
          // .....
           // show  
        }else if(state == 0){
           // hide
        }
    });
```

Learn about [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) from here

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can reach the Activity digging through parent views:

```
Activity act = (Activity) webViewResult.getParent().getParent().....so on
```